# Laravel 4: Error execute migrate

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have this migration php file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriesTable.php extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id'); 
            $table->string('name',200); 
            $table->string('description',200); 
            $table->boolean('is_disabled');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('categories');
    }

}
```

Then I executed php artisan migrate and got this error:

Fatal error:  Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::requireOnce(): Failed opening required 'WWW_DIRECTORY/app/database/migrations/2013_11_23_154547_cre
ate_categories_table.php'

Aynone knows why this can be happening? I'm learning to use Laravel..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not declaring your class properly. That `.php` extension needs to be removed. Instead of

`class CreateCategoriesTable.php extends Migration {`

use

`class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration {`

Comment: Thanks... It was an error in the name when I created by command line that class

Comment: It works! And don't forget to make sure your file doesn't have a trailing .php! `create_categories_table.php.php`...